# Hamburger toggle button working locally but not when deployed

Tags: wordpress, toggle

The code below renders a hamburger toggle button that is working perfectly fine when I test it on localhost, but that fails to work after website is deployed to a remote server.

I've tried multiple different approaches to solve the issue, including checking for possible jQuery enqueuing issues, but nothing worked so far.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

  <div class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <?php
             wp_nav_menu( array(
             'menu'              => 'primary',
             'theme_location'    => 'mobile',
             'depth'             => 2,
             'container'         => 'div',
             'container_class'   => '',
             'container_id'      => '',
             'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
             'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
             'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
             );
        ?>
      </div>

</nav>
```

When online, the button is indeed visible, but is totally unresponsive when clicked.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue meanwhile by adding "type="button" to this line of code:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
</button>
```